# Flashvar and Web Handlers with URL Variables

Tags: flash, ashx

I have a situation that calls for a web handler to be used as one of the parameters into flashvars. The url for the web handler includes a variable for the language...

```
<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"file=http://localhost:13196/scripts/Video.ashx?id=abc&l=es-MX&image=http://localhost:13196...>
```

The problem is that when the handler is called the context no longer includes the the variable l=es-MX. I believe that is because the language variable is being treated as a separate parameter. How can I make sure that the language variable is treated as a variable of the file parameter?

Thanks for the help,

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get around this is to use url encoding.

```
<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"file=http://localhost:13196/scripts/Video.ashx?id=abc%26l=es-MX&image=http://localhost:13196...>
```

The & after the id has been replaced with a %26, which represents an & in url encoding.